# Spring hibernate entity graph not populating the object

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the the following classes, i can see the select being done in logs with outer joins when my spring data calls the find commentById... but when i inspect the object in intelliJK there is no data.. instead another select takes place when i do comment.getUser().. why is my entity grahh not loading data.

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    //...
}


@Entity
public class Post {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
    
    //...
}



@NamedEntityGraph(
  name = "comment-entity-graph",
  attributeNodes = {
    @NamedAttributeNode("user"),
    @NamedAttributeNode("post", subgraph = "post.comments"),
  },

  subgraph= { @NamedSubgraph=(name= "post.comments", attributeNodes= { @NamedAttributeNode("comments")})
  }
)
@Entity
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String reply;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn
    private Post post;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn
    private User user;
    
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually specify the entity graph to be used when performing the query. With Spring Data JPA you do that by adding an [`@EntityGraph`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/EntityGraph.html) annotation on your query method.

```
public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<Comment, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(value = "comment-entity-graph")
    Comment findById(Long id);
}
```

For a more verbose example see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs

Comment: So i did that... and then what i noticed was that the debugger did not show the object values including primitives. But in the code when i did a get on child object.. no additional select was output.. so the object ahs to have been loaded... not sure why intelliJ is not showing it..